# Problem on number theory

Tags: number-theory

> For any integer $n\ge 1$, let
> $d(n)=$ number of positive divisors of $n$
> $v(n)=$ number of distinct prime divisors of $n$
> $\omega(n)=$ number of positive divisors of $n$ counted with multiplicity
> For example, if $p$ is a prime, then
> $d(p)=2, v(p)=v(p^2)=2, \omega(p)=2$
>
> 1. if $n\ge 1000$, then $d(n)>\log n$
> 2. there exist $n$ such that $d(n)> \sqrt n$
> 3. for every $n$, $2^{v(n)}\ge d(n)\le 2^{\omega(n)}$
> 4. if $\omega(n)=\omega(m)$, then $d(n)=d(m)$

Now $4$ is incorrect. Because if $n$ has divisors $1,n_1,n_1,n_2,n$ and $m$ has divisors $1,m_1,m_2,m_3,m$, then obviously $4$ does not hold.
$1$ can be true. For $n=1000=2^3.5^3$, $d(n)=16>\log 1000=\log 10^3=3\log 10=3$
$2$ also seems correct for $n= 2,3,4$ etc
I have no idea for $3$.

So I wish your valuable opinions on option $3$ and about the correct one among the above options.

**N.B: There is no mention in the question whether I have to choose the correct one or the false one. Since I am unsure about option $3$, I cannot decide the right one.**

Comment: One of the inequalities in 3 is wrong. Did you mean to write it like that?

Comment: @apelt001 there is no typo

Comment: No, $1.$ can't be true. Certainly you have already tried a prime number, like $n=1013$??

Comment: 2 is correct for $n=2$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde in that way, $1$ can be or can not be true. Because for $1000$ it holds.

Comment: No it is false. It says, **if** $n\ge 1000$, and $n=1013$ is greater than $1000$, then $d(n)>\log(n)$, which is false for $n=1013$.

Comment: 3 would be true if it read $2^{\nu(n)} \leq d(n) \leq 2^{\omega(n)}$, so whoever wrote this problem just switched one of the inequalities. This can be proven using the multiplicativity property of the divisor function $d(n)$. That is, $d(mn) = d(m)d(n)$ whenever $m$ and $n$ are coprime. The result follows then by checking the inequality for $m=p^k$ and $n=q^r$, where $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1$ is not true because $d(p^{\alpha})=\alpha+1$ for all prime $p$ while $\log(p^{\alpha})=\alpha\log p$, if $1$ were true, we would have $\alpha+1>\alpha\log p$ for $\alpha$ large enough which is not for $p=3$ for instance. As for $2$, it is true because $d(2)=2>\sqrt{2}$ therefore $n=2$ fits. $3$ is false, you can prove that $d(n)\geqslant 2^{v(n)}$ and the inequality is strict when there is a prime $p$ such that $p^2|n$, for instance $d(4)=3>2=2^{v(4)}$. You've already proved that $4$ is false. **However**, if $3$ had a typo, i.e. if it were $2^{v(n)}\leqslant d(n)\leqslant 2^{\omega(n)}$ instead, then $3$ would be true.

Comment: What about $n=2$ or $3$ for option 2?

Comment: Oh my bad I thought it was for all $n$. Then $2$ is correct, you are right.

Comment: One small query that I need to meet. Can I say $1$ is wrong? Because it holds for some numbers and also does not hold for other ones.

Comment: $1$ states that $d(n)>\log n$ for ALL $n\geqslant 1000$, if it's not the case for one $n\geqslant 1000$, then $1$ is false, even though the inequality is true for some $n\geqslant 1000$.

Comment: @ManjoyDas You should review the meaning of "if .. then". It is an implication $\Longrightarrow$.